# JSP 2 tag files “/WEB-INF/tags” not found

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

Yes, this question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586026/jsp-2-tag-files-web-inf-tags-not-found) but with the huge difference that I am working with a TLD file rather than a taglib-to-folder declaration.

Okay, my setup is the following: I am migrating a pure-Java tag library to almost-JSP (some tags will still survive their Java form). I had a TLD defined under my `classpath:META-INF` folder. Some tags are defined as classes, while others are now defined as JSP 2 tag files under `/WEB-INF/tags`. Example given:

```
<tag-file>
    <name>navbar</name>
    <path>/WEB-INF/tags/navbar.tag</path>
    <display-name>Navbar</display-name>
</tag-file>
```

This all works great under Eclipse, though I had to manually set up `Web Deployment Assembly` from `src/META-INF` to `WEB-INF`, otherwise the TLD file won't be recognized by Tomcat.

After happily debugging the code I have tried to create a WAR version of my application to be deployed to SIT. Despite the presence of the `tags` directory under `WEB-INF` along with the JSP 2 tag files, I am still unable to run the application.

And the error iiiiiiiiiiiiis:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /login.jsp (line: 3, column: 0) File [/WEB-INF/tags/navbar.tag] not found
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:275)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:91)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:335)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:368)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:471)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1435)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.__compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet._serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

The TLD is declared as usual

```
<%@ taglib prefix="example" uri="http://www.example.org/example.tld"%>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the partial solution (I will update this answer if and when I find the complete one).

It looks like that if I deploy the TLD file under `classpath`, then I should deploy the tags accordingly.

I had to replace `<path>/WEB-INF/tags/navbar.tag</path>` with `<path>/META-INF/tags/navbar.tag</path>` and move all the tags under `classpath:META-INF/tags`.

This way, the WAR package is working.

Unfortunately, I broke my Eclipse setup, so the workaround was to manually setup a `Deployment assembly` entry from `src/META-INF/tags` to `META-INF/tags` because the tag file now references `META-INF` folder. Pretty ugly, but suitable for development at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

I've had a similar experience. My project uses tags to keep navigation menus in a single place and use them on many jsp pages. I am using Tomcat 8. Some of the things I have learned along the way are:

- The tags directory contains *.tld and *.tag files you are creating.

My configuration is Tomcat 8,Java 7,JEE 6,Servlet 3.1 and JSP 2.2. I am using a plain eclipse jsp project. (no maven) Here is my tld file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE xml>
    <taglib version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/j2ee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

      <tlib-version>1.2.5</tlib-version>
      <jsp-version>2.2</jsp-version>
      <short-name>taglibs</short-name>
      <description>jsp tag library for the navigation code</description>
      <tag>
        <name>navMenu</name>
        <tag-class>ksServer.navTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>tagdependent</body-content>
      </tag>  
    </taglib>
```

The beginning lines of a typical webapp jsp file are

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
    <%@ page import="ksClasses.KsvrmSqlAgent" %>
    <%@ page import="org.slf4j.Logger" %>
    <%@ page import="org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="kr" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as an answer to my question. The servlet part is irrelevant, the fact that project must have specific folder name is incorrect (you have a certain degree of freedom in customizing folder names), and most important there is a reason why I want to keep the TLD file in a jar rather than in the `/WEB-INF/tags` directory. I want to suggest you to keep answers short and focused on topic. I will edit your answer removing the parts that are irrelevant to the tags world.